# Asking for an idiom according to literal translation

Tags: idioms

I translated a sentence into English:

> When the details are ignored, the whole problem will be ignored unintentionally

Seems like a logical sentence that says when you don't consider all details while solving a problem, it'll affect the result and the whole problem. I'd like to know if there's an idiomatic expression meaning the same.

Comment: To me, it isn't an understandable sentence. Can you give some context of how your sentence is used? Maybe "you can't see the forest for the trees"?

Comment: @JLG: I cannot provide more context than I already did, as I said it's talking about a situation where you're told not to interfere in minor issues and you're saying that details are important or something like that. Could you elaborate what the idiom you said means?

Comment: @Gigili: “You can’t see the forest for the trees” means that details (trees) can prevent you from seeing the whole (forest) of something. “For” in that idiom means “because of”, as in “He left without her, and for that, she hated him”.

Comment: It's not exactly an idiom, but you could certainly say, for example *"today's complacency is tomorrow's headache"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what OP wants to convey. If she's trying to point out that solving some particular problem is actually much harder than might be thought by others who don't understand exactly what will be involved, @Matt's *"The devil's in the detail"* is probably appropriate (it's often pluralised now, but I've always known it in the singular).

If on the other hand, OP is trying to convey that failure to conscientiously attend to all details  will result in an inadequate solution, I suggest the proverb

> [If a job's worth doing, it's worth doing well.](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/12108/)

Comment: I explained it twice, something is wrong that it's still unclear to you.

Comment: @Gigili: Either of my two interpretations are consistent with your "explanation". Something is wrong if you cannot see the difference between *the nature of the situation*, and *what you wish to say about it*.

Comment: Apologies for failing to realise the gender issue. I've let your edit go through because of that, but to be honest I don't think you're really justified in changing *"not completely clear"* to just *"not clear"*. The reason for that extra word was that the distinction I'm making is quite a fine one. Your edit simply seems designed to subtly weaken the point I'm making, so you can more easily disagree with me.

Comment: None of your "interpretation"s seems suitable to me because it's talking about a situation where you're told not to interfere in minor issues and you're saying that details are important and we cannot ignore them. There's something wrong obviously.

Comment: You're right, I edited that part because the edit must be more than 6 characters. I get offended when someone addresses me as "he".

Comment: @Gigili: What can I say? I don't see exactly the context where you want to make your statement, or exactly what you want it to convey. From your responses, it seems you mean *"There is no need to consider the bigger picture/problem, since it will automatically be resolved by dealing with the details"*. But your question text seems to come at it from the other end - *"If you don't deal with the details, the bigger problem will not be resolved"*. These are genuine differences of emphasis, which will each apply in different contexts.

Comment: The latter is the case.

Comment: @Gigili: In that case I maintain that my second offering is at least as appropriate as the metaphorical *pennies/pounds* usage, if not more so.

Comment: Which one is your second offering? "Penny wise, pound foolish!"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2767/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-gigili)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The contents of this answer seem more appropriate as a comment (or at least edit to preserve the actual proverb as an answer and move the rest to a comment).

Comment: @Mitch: Arguably so if you've followed the entire discussion between me and OP, but so far as addressing the question text itself is concerned, I don't think so. There are two major contexts which could apply; I've addressed both, and explained clearly *why* I did so. I'm not going to lose any sleep over the fact that it doesn't get any upvotes, but I think nothing I wrote was superfluous - if anything, I might edit back in the word OP removed from my text.

Answer (score 11):

The best saying I can think of is

> The devil's in the details

Which mean that the smallest parts of a problem are the most challenging.

The opposite of what you want, I think, is

> Look after the pennies and the pounds will look after themselves

Meaning, if you take care of the little things the big things will fall into place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matt, does it mean "details are important
?

Comment: Yes, both sayings mean that.

Comment: I'm not sure either saying exactly fits OP's context. The first one applies when you're pointing out that resolving some superficially straightforward problem will actually be quite tricky when you get down to specifics. The second is only normally used in relation to gradually accumulating *savings*, not to identifying small problems today which if left unaddressed will result in **big** problems at some later date. Which is what I think OP is getting at.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I say about the second, it implies the opposite of what Gigili wants. I disagree that it only applies to savings. I certainly use it with a more broad meaning.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a transparent extension of meaning, so it would always be understood in context. I must admit though, if the boss were castigating me for spending too much time focussing on minor details, and I said that to him, I'd fully expect the rejoinder **"Penny wise, pound foolish!"**

Answer (score 1):

Another similar idiom that's used is "*the tip of the iceberg*."  Here's an example:

> Frank: "We only had two users who complained."
>
> Ernest: "Yes, but that's just the tip of the iceberg."

The idea, of course, is that we only see a little bit of the iceberg above the water, but that's only a small indicator of a much more massive, unseen, dangerous chunk of ice below the surface.  In the dialog above, Ernest is telling Frank that, even though only two users have formally complained, there are likely dozens more who are very unhappy.

The idiom could also be used like this:

> Seth: "I'm hearing a funny noise in my car.  I think it's time for some new tires."
>
> Beth: "That's probably just the tip of the iceberg!"

In this case, Beth is agreeing that Seth may need new tires, but is also guessing that the mechanic will find plenty else that needs fixing, too.  She might be especially prone to say this if Seth's car is old and falling apart.

As I said, it's *similar*.  Maybe not exact, but along the same lines.