# Is it grammatical to finish a sentence with "also"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends, also-too

In the following text, I wonder if it's grammatical to finish the sentence with *also*. it does sound weird to me. The sentence sound incomplete somehow and makes the audience wait for more.

> Here this equation must be understood to mean not only that both sides have the same value when they are defined, but also that when either side of the equation is undefined, the other is also.

I know it's *the other is also [undefined]*, but I've never seen a construction like that. If it's grammatical, what is it called?

Comment: There's a comma missing: "the other is, also."

Comment: @PeterShor: There is no comma where you suggested.

Comment: @Gigili There isn’t one now, but there should be, which I trust is @Peter’s point.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's acceptable to ***end*** the sentence with "also" (I personally don't like it one bit), it's stylistically appalling to use the word twice in the same sentence like that.

Comment: @tchrist: I got Peter's point and I was pointing out that in my book there is no comma before also.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["also is" at the end of sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89843/also-is-at-the-end-of-sentence)

Comment: Surely the statement in the sentence is a truism for all equations - it doesn't need to be stated. Speaking as a mathematician, I'd expect the domain of an equation, whether describing a function or a looser relation, to be specified - ie the whole mathematical 'statement' is a nonsense otherwise. eg: y = x squared divided by x (x not equal to 0)

Comment: That's the kind of sentence I don't look forward to reading.

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly grammatical, and can be substituted by other words and phrases *too* and *as well*.

I don't use *also* there myself, as it sounds rather American to me, but I accept it.

In this case it is a bit awkward because of the repetition of *also* so it might be clearer if you used one of the other possibilities.

Traditionally it is simply an adverb.

Comment: As a fellow Brit, I also find it decidedly "odd". I'd *never* move that *"also"* to the end of the sentence. But is there any evidence that Americans find it any more acceptable than we do?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Count me out.  It doesn’t seem quite right over here, either.  But notice my comma before *either*.

Comment: @tchrist: That comma doesn't bother me, but I wouldn't normally bother with it either. And in *that* sentence I would *never* include the comma, since if you asked me to read it out loud I wouldn't pause at that point. I'm guessing the tendency to include it regardless of the potential spoken cadence is stronger for Americans, since Peter Shor would like one before OP's trailing *"also"*.

Comment: Non-traditionally, _also_ etc are pragmatic markers with conjunctive role showing addition. I rarely feel kindly about the adverb dustbin, but...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think I'd pause slightly at that point reading it out loud, which is why I'd put in the comma. If I didn't want to pause, I'd have to say "the other also is."

Comment: @Peter Shor: By *at that point* do you mean before OP's *also*, or before my first *either*? I'm in no doubt I'd have to include quite a long pause in OP's example (if I could bring myself to say it at all) because without the pause I'd have a strong expectation of *more words to follow, within the same sentence.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I meant before the OP's *also*. (I see I misread what you meant by "that comma".) But I'd use a slight pause and put a comma before your first *either,* as well.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Haha I guess we all have our particular speech rhythms - I "read" your comma there, but when it was "articulated" by the voice in my head, there was no pause the first time around. I had to consciously force myself to add the pause when I re-scanned the words.

Comment: For reasons I simply cannot figure out, I have to disagree with the first sentence in this answer: the sentence as it stands now is just not grammatical to me. “The other is, too” is fine, as is “The other is, as well”… but substituting _also_ breaks grammaticality in my head. Moving it up before the verb doesn't help either: “*The other also is” is equally impossible for me. For _also_ to be usable, the subject complement must be unelided: “The other is undefined also” and “The other is also undefined” are both fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Colin it is grammatical.  As noted in question, the word *undefined* has been elided at the end.  I also agree that *too* or *as well* can be substituted in place of *also* , and imagine those might be used more frequently.  However, I don't like any of those forms and would use another.  In ascending order of preference:

> ... the other is also.
>   ... the other is, also.
>   ... the other is as well.
>   ... the other is too.
>   ... the other also is undefined.
>   ... the other also is.
>   ... so is the other.

Comment: Per my comment to the question, since the word "also" has already been used in the preceding clause, it's absolutely *awful* to repeat it, regardless of the exact wording. So *in OP's specific context* your "order of preference" should have #3 in the penultimate position. Other than that, I agree completely.

Comment: I'm perhaps less sensitive to the repetition of *also*, and don't regard its repetition as “absolutely awful”; nevertheless, I now agree “the other is as well” should be preferred to the variants with *also* in them.  But not preferred to  “so is the other”.

Comment: Absolutely - the last one is by far the best to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the original:

> Here this equation must be understood to mean not only that both sides have the same value when they are defined, but also that when either side of the equation is undefined, the other is also.

to this:

> This equation assumes that both sides have the same value when both sides are defined or both undefined when either side is undefined.

Comment: Hi @lep, welcome to ELU. Your rephrasing is definitely an improvement on OP's original. But note that he's not asking for a better form of words - he's simply asking whether his example would be considered acceptable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [I am not a he](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60956/asking-for-an-idiom-according-to-literal-translation#comment116346_60981).

Comment: Lol! It's an ELU slapdown! :-)

Comment: @Gigili: Sorry - I'll try to remember that! (I think I "sorta" knew, but forgot :)