# Missing the trees for the forest

Tags: phrase-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking for an idiom according to literal translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60956/asking-for-an-idiom-according-to-literal-translation)

I think I came up with a new phrase, similar to the devil in details. Appreciate if you find it applicable and mildly amusing.

**Missing the trees for the forest**

It describes the situation where you have a grand scheme but haven't thought through or screw up on implementation details. Somewhat like designing a beautiful, impressive, useful (and other such adjectives) architecture of a building but using bad quality bricks and misaligning them when laying. The completed structure looks impressive but does not falls apart when used.

Are there any other phrases that describe this situation?

PS: This is not missing the *forest* for the *trees*, which is a five hundred year old phrase that his phrase twists around for the reverse meaning.

Comment: What is your new phrase? Do you mean "Missing the trees for the forest"?

Comment: Yes, that's the phrase. I should add it to the question text as well....done

Comment: 115k hits on Google. 7 cites in COCA, 1 in BNC. You have not invented anything new.

Comment: Care to link me to one hit? They are for Missing the *forest* for the *trees*, which is different. I could only find one link, http://lesswrong.com/lw/13k/missing_the_trees_for_the_forest/, but it describes a different concept

Comment: @Variable: To one hit? Here are [all 115000 of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22missing+the+trees+for+the+forest%22&aq=f&oq=%22missing+the+trees+for+the+forest%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j61j0l3j62.3922&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). And here's [a COCA query](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=20515878).

Comment: @RegDwighт do you see a difference between "missing trees for forest" and "missing forest for trees"? (Hint: the second and fourth words are different)

Comment: @Variable: do *you* see it? I have *copypasted your exact phrase* and *enclosed it in quotes*.

Comment: All this hoo-ha over whether or not OP's example is truly original and/or amusing is kinda forgetting about the fact that OP is in fact asking for an alternative expression. [The devil's in the detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60958/2637), but to my mind this question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: While the OP actually used "the devil's in the details" in their question, I actually think that their "invented" expression, "miss the trees for the forest" feels more like you don't want to overlook the details for the big picture which I would interpret as a more positive statement than "the devil's in the details".  That's just my perspective, given the OP's question.

Comment: @Kristina: I removed the 's' because ***I*** don't use it. Badly-phrased as it might be, OP's example concerns an endeavour immaculate in conception, but woefully inadequate if/when implemented. Granted, you usually say "the devil's in the detail" *before* implementation (if it was *after*, you'd say "they didn't pay attention to detail"). But the standard cliche inverted by OP is also normally used negatively of things in the past/present, rather than as a positive injunction concerning future endeavours. To me, it's a dup, even if the original's answers could be improved upon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers nah, we are not forgetting about that fact at all. An actual answer to the question of what alternatives there are was provided simultaneously with the brouhaha. And in fact OP's very own request to kill the question was rejected. Precisely because with the brouhaha aside, there's still a question to be answered here.

Comment: All this thrashing about the "new phrase" is caused by poor wording of the question title. In the question title, please take out the "new phrase" and put your question there.

Comment: @RegDwighт: I see what you mean, but I was really thinking about all the downvotes when I commented. As you say, there's still a [valid] question to be answered, so I can only suppose those downvotes were from people who didn't think OP's inversion was particularly original and/or amusing. I'm not convinced *devil in the detail* exactly hits the spot, but for OP's context it does seem closer than jwpat7's IOED here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask, “Are there any other phrases that describe this situation?”.  It appears that there are; examples follow.

In an article called [Missing the trees for the forest](http://nicpetrossi.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/missing-the-trees-for-the-forest/), N. Petrossi gives an alternate wording:  “... they have focused on all of Orange County’s home market stats and failed to see that it’s the “Trees,” the individual cities with their individual areas that are especially important.”

In another article called [Missing the trees for the forest](http://systematicrelativestrength.com/2011/09/02/missing-the-trees-for-the-forest/), Dorsey Wright MM rephrases it as “Even if the economy is crummy and returns from the market are not enticing, there may be plenty of opportunity.”

In another article called [Missing the trees for the forest](http://lesswrong.com/lw/13k/missing_the_trees_for_the_forest/), Yvain says “when people consider an idea in isolation, they tend to make good decisions. When they consider an idea a symbol of a vast overarching narrative, they tend to make very bad decisions.”

A more complete analysis appears in  another article called “[Missing the trees for the forest](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20658836): a construal level account of the illusion of explanatory depth”.  The authors write:

> An illusion of explanatory depth (IOED) occurs when people believe they understand a concept more deeply than they actually do. To date, IOEDs have been identified only in mechanical and natural domains, occluding why they occur and suggesting that their implications are quite limited. Six studies illustrated that IOEDs occur because people adopt an inappropriately abstract construal style when they assess how well they understand concrete concepts. ...

Following that reference, the phrase  “illusion of explanatory depth” or the acronym IOED seem like reasonable alternative wordings of “Missing the trees for the forest”.

Comment: At lease a couple of these interpret this to be taking about starting with a individual and ignoring the big picture. I seem to think it more effectively means concentrating on big picture while missing out on details. Perhaps I have it backwards :)

Comment: @MiserableVariable, all of the linked articles are about overlooking smaller elements because of concentrating on (or being blinded by) the big picture.  However, labeling the first three quotations as alternative wordings of “Missing the trees for the forest” is facetious (ie an attempt at humor).